# Python argparse to ignore concatenated args?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have a question about argparse in Python 2.7. I'm trying to ignore arguments that aren't used as I have a batch file that passes arguments to several Python scripts and different scripts need to pull out different args.

For example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
```

If I specify each argument on its own, it works fine:

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['-a',' -b'])
print args
# Namespace(a=True)
print unknown
# [' -b']
```

But if I specify them in concatenated format:

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['-ab'])
```

I get this:

```
: error: argument -a: ignored explicit argument 'b'
```

However if I add this line to the code above:

```
parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')
```

Then this works:

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['-ab'])
print args
# Namespace(a=True, b=True)
print unknown
# []
```

So it appears I can use the concatenated format only with known arguments. I wonder if there's a way to use concatenated format where it can just pull out the args it knows about? The only alternative I can think of is just to define all the arguments in all the Python scripts, but then it seems like that would pollute the -h help display?

Comment: This is how it works. If you look at the method: it's called `parse_KNOWN_args()`.

Comment: But isn't an argument -ab really just a shortened version of two separate arguments, a and b, with a known and b not? If I use -a -b then it works even though -b is not known. I just want the option to use -ab instead since that manner of entry is more familiar to many admins.

Comment: Then define the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't encountered this issue before, but I can imagine why it is happening.  But I'd have to examine the code to be sure of the details.

'-ab' is passed to a nested function called `consume_optional`.  This has special code to recognize and spit up these concatenated args.  It recognizes '-a'.  Since it does not take any arguments, it assumes 'b' means '-b'.  If '-b' is not defined, it issues this error message.  It does not throw it into the `extras` list.

A stand alone '-b' string would be put into `extras`, but that occurs at the start of this `consume_optionals` function.  You may think of '-ab' and '-a -b' as the same thing, but the parsing route is different, resulting in different errors.

Try `help=argparse.SUPPRESS` for '-b'.  That should reduce 'pollution' of the help display.  You may still have to use a custom 'usage'.

'-ab' could still have problems in a parser where `-b' is defined, but '-a' is not.  The whole string would put in the 'extras' list.

Comment: Awesome. I'll follow this for my solution, where I'll add entries for all the possible args and then use help=argparse.SUPPRESS for the scripts that don't use them. Works well.